# Calling JQuery function from xhtml in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a jquery function defined in an external js file :
myJquery.js

```
    (function($) {  
       $.fn.test = function (options) {  
           //Extended default options
           var opts = $.extend({
                  chars: 0
 }, options);
...doSomething...
})(jQuery);
```

Inclding this file in xhtml as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_/js/myJquery.js"/>
```

and trying to access as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("input.testClass").each(function() {
                          $(this).test({
                                chars:10
                         });
                   });
 });
```

But getting js error saying 'test' function not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` function is scoped to the external file space, not the global environment.  If you are sure that jQuery has command of the `$` then append your function without the `function($)` wrapper.

EDIT: while the above may still be relevant for others ... it does work fine (at least for just showing the alert) with the `}` in place:

external file inlcuded with `<script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>`

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.test = function (options) {
       //Extended default options
       var opts = $.extend({chars: 0}, options);
       alert('boo: '+opts.chars);
   }
})(jQuery);
```

in page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("h1").each(function() {
              $(this).test({
                    chars:10
             });
       });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i removed function($) from myJquery.js (removed first and last line from above myJquery.js snippet), but stil same issue. Did i understand ur suggestion correctly !!

Comment: Ha well, didn't even notice, but you are missing a curly bracket to close the function declaration.